# How to count multiple distinct values?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have written a DAX which is supposed to mark a 1 in the cell if the Organisation has been with multiple (distinct) sectors, however, I keep running into some issues.

```
Dup = 
CALCULATE( 
    COUNT('Inspection Scheduling Spreadsheet'[Licensed Establishment / Organisation]),
    FILTER(
        VALUES ('Inspection Scheduling Spreadsheet'[Licensed Establishment / Organisation] ),
        DISTINCTCOUNT( 'Inspection Scheduling Spreadsheet'[Sector]) > 1 
    )
)
```

The column `Dup` should be returning `0` because the organisation has been with the same sector.
[image]

Whereas, this is when Dup should return a 1
[image]
So whenever an organisation has been with more than one sector the column Dup should return a `1` else `0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this below code-

```
Dup =

VAR current_row_org = MIN('Inspection Scheduling Spreadsheet'[Licensed Establishment / Organisation])

VAR dist_count =  
CALCULATE( 
    DISTINCTCOUNT('Inspection Scheduling Spreadsheet'[Sector]),
    FILTER(
        ALL('Inspection Scheduling Spreadsheet'),
        'Inspection Scheduling Spreadsheet'[Licensed Establishment / Organisation] = current_row_org
    )
)

RETURN IF(dist_count > 1,1,0)
```

Comment: I tested the above code and everything just returns 0

Comment: This should work. Did you changed any part in the code? If so, please share the new Measure code here.

Comment: I just created a custom column and placed the entire code inside and it returns 0 for every organisation

Comment: In case of custom column, just create the first variable as - VAR current_row_org = 'Inspection Scheduling Spreadsheet'[Licensed Establishment / Organisation]